# Loop Through Self List

Tags: java, loops, recursion, arraylist

I have this Person class which has a list of Person (s). How do I loop through persons and check if each object inside of that has a list of Person(s) and if each object inside that has a list and so on and so forth? Everything I can think of is pretty limiting as far as how nested it gets. I can write a recursive loop but that gets me to the first level deep, but not sure how to get x levels deep with recursion. I am sure somebody has come accross this problem in the past and it shouldn't be that difficult but I just can't quite wrap my head around it. Any and all ideas are welcomed!

```
public class Person {
    // other fields removed for simplicity
    private long id;
    private List<Person> persons;

    public List<Person> getPersons() {
        return debates;
    }
}

// essentially I am looking for a way to make this unlimited level nested looping
private void loopPersons() {
    Person person = new Person();

    if(person.getPersons() != null && !person.getPersons().isEmpty()) {
        for(Person person1 : person.getPersons()) {
            if(person1.getPersons() != null && !person1.getPersons().isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println(person1.getId());

                for(Person person2 : person1.getPersons()) {
                    if(person2.getPersons() != null && !person2.getPersons().isEmpty()) {
                        System.out.println(person2.getId());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
The answer by Brian in this other post (scroll down) is essentially what does it. [iterate through recursive objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32436080/iterate-through-recursive-objects?fbclid=IwAR0hWq6EvxSiGaWpkq9E9WcJ09r_2BzkbeMx95KHOr473AVPkXEXD5J_-GI)

Comment: if you can include the loopPerson as member of Person you can do the looping x level . Just think about it.

Comment: @AnkurJyotiPhukan I am not following; can you elaborate please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.List;

class Person {
    // other fields removed for simplicity
    private long id;
    private List<Person> persons;

    public Person(long id, List<Person> persons) {
        this.id = id;
        this.persons = persons;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setPersons(List<Person> persons) {
        this.persons = persons;
    }

    public List<Person> getPersons() {
        return persons;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [id=" + id + ", persons=" + persons + "]";
    }

    public void showAll() {
        if (getPersons() == null || getPersons().isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }
        getPersons().get(0).showAll();
        System.out.println(getPersons());
    }
}
```

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person p1 = new Person(1,List.of(new Person(11, List.of(new Person(111, List.of(new Person(1111, null))),
                                                                new Person(112, List.of(new Person(1121, null))),
                                                                new Person(113, List.of(new Person(1131, null))))),
                                        new Person(12, List.of(new Person(121, List.of(new Person(1211, null))))),
                                        new Person(13, List.of(new Person(131, List.of(new Person(1311, null)))))));
        p1.showAll();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[Person [id=1111, persons=null]]
[Person [id=111, persons=[Person [id=1111, persons=null]]], Person [id=112, persons=[Person [id=1121, persons=null]]], Person [id=113, persons=[Person [id=1131, persons=null]]]]
[Person [id=11, persons=[Person [id=111, persons=[Person [id=1111, persons=null]]], Person [id=112, persons=[Person [id=1121, persons=null]]], Person [id=113, persons=[Person [id=1131, persons=null]]]]], Person [id=12, persons=[Person [id=121, persons=[Person [id=1211, persons=null]]]]], Person [id=13, persons=[Person [id=131, persons=[Person [id=1311, persons=null]]]]]]
```

Comment: If any person has more than one child your code could fail to print all persons. Also your code will run infinite times, producing a stack overflow, if a parent is a child of one of its children.

Comment: *If any person has more than one child your will fail for that.* - No @BeWu, it's not true. I've updated the example person with more children.

Comment: @BeWu  - The person with id `1` has three children and person with id `11` has also three children. If you look at the output, they all are getting printed. What else are you expecting?

Comment: Sorry I have misread the output. But you could still produce a stackoverflow.

Comment: @BeWu - Logically, a parent should not be a child of one of its children and your code should ensure it doesn't happen. Nevertheless, can you show me an example where my code would produce a StackOverflow?

Comment: @BeWu - I didn't take it offensive at all. In fact, I wanted to help you understand recursion and that's why I posted a new example and asked you to check the output. Since you already have my program and a sample example, you can create other examples easily. I would like you to think of an example to prove your hypothesis. If you succeed, it will be a great help for everyone.

Comment: Just add the very first person object not a new one as a child to one of it's children. That way it should call the function to show it's children again and again.

Comment: In this case/question, Person is just like a real human. I can have a kids, my kids can have kids, their kids can have no kids etc, but their kids can never by my parent. I hope it helps one of the questions above regarding parent-child relationship.

Comment: Exactly! Thanks, @NoobLord1234 for clarifying it further. BeWu - why would one create a recursive data structure? Its the responsibility of the programmer to avoid creating a recursive data structure. I had done a similar silly mistake a few months ago (check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59345674/java-lang-stackoverflowerror-when-trying-to-add-the-same-instance-of-list-multip)

Comment: An example for such a data structure would be two entities a person and the corresponding address, often you would want to go from one to the other and vice versa with a two way mapping ( I.e. with hibernate @OneToMany and @ManyToOne) that would produce a recursive data structure as you described it.

Comment: Person personMom = new Person().setComment("mom");
personMom.setId(1L);

Person personDaughter = new Person().setComment("mom's daughter");
personDaughter.setId(2L);

Person personSon = new Debate().setComment("mom's son");
personSon.setId(3L);

Person personDaughtersSon = new Person().setComment("mom's daughter's son");
personDaughtersSon.setId(4L);

personDaughter.addDebate(personDaughtersSon);
personMom.addDebate(personDaughter);
personMom.addDebate(personSon);

personMom.showAll(); ->

Comment: Outcome of that is:

[Person [id=4, persons=null]]
[Person [id=2, persons=[Person [id=4, persons=null]]], Person [id=3, persons=null]]



But that is wrong because id 4 should not appear on its own as it is not a parent.

Answer (score 2):

You might just be looking for some flattening on the lines of making use of recursion with a tail condition. This could be similar to the following implementation

```
// essentially I am looking for a way to make this unlimited level nested looping
private List<Person> loopPersons(Person person, List<Person> flattened) {
    if (person.getPersons() == null || person.getPersons().isEmpty()) {
        return flattened;
    } else {
        flattened.addAll(person.getPersons());
        person.getPersons().forEach(p -> loopPersons(p, flattened));
    }
    return flattened;
}
```

***Note***: The code is not tested and is to depict a possible approach that you can take if you think over the same lines.

Comment: The flattened parameter would work better as a Set to remove possible duplicates. It should also include a check if a person was already checked to remove the possibility of a stack overflow related to infinite recursion. Just in case a person is a child of one of it's own children.

Comment: @BeWu true that's the reason I quoted "similar", the code is not tested but to depict a possible approach that the OP could take. But yeah, I should put that as a note in the answer as well.